# Javascript only read certain char from input

Tags: javascript

```
var name = prompt("Enter Name,Barry");
document.write(name);
```

I want to do exactly this, but only print the first three letters of the 'name'

Comment: `name.substring(0,3)`

Comment: substr is your friend.

Comment: Like this? doucment.write(name.substring(0,0));

Comment: `.substring(startIndex, endIndex)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var name = prompt("Enter Name,Barry").slice(0, 3);
document.write(name)
```

Try this out it may help.

Comment: Thank you. This workers.